# Apple reject app because of Ipv6 In AfNetwoking 3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipv6, afnetworking-3

Apple reject my app because of Ipv6. I am developing app in Objective C with Afnetworking 3.1. I have read in Github AFnetworking 3.1 is support ipv6, but than also apple not approve the app.

I am using post method of AFNetworking. I am using following code for call API.

```
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager POST:API_URL parameters:dictRequest
         progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

         }
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
//              NSLog(@"success : %@",responseObject);

              if([[responseObject objectForKey:KEY_status_code] integerValue] == 1){
                  [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:[responseObject objectForKey:KEY_msg]];
              }
              else{
                  [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[responseObject objectForKey:KEY_msg]];
              }
          }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
              NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
              [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:nil];
          }];
```

Comment: submit your query to apple , apple will surely accpet

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i have already try this.

Comment: you have a doucment related to this

Comment: if yes add the **expedited app review** to apple

Answer (score 0):

- Your API_URL is domain or  IPv4 address literals! If it is IPv4 address literals, then this request can't run in NAT64 network, as a result your app will be rejected! Please make sure that the API_URL is DOMAIN style.

Comment: No, IPv4 addresses do *not* "work fine".  Domains work fine.  IPv4 addresses fail completely on IPv6-only network.  iOS simulates IPv4 over an IPv6 network using its DNS resolver (which is IMO a layering violation design mistake, but that's another rant for another day).  If a domain name resolves to an IPv4 address, the resolver constructs an IPv4-over-IPv6 tunnel address and provides that synthesized IPv6 address to the app.  With a hardcoded IPv4 address, there's no name resolution, which means that process doesn't work, at least according to Apple's official documentation on the subject.

Comment: @user102008 I think you are missing Knowledge about IPv6 in iOS 9! First make sure you readed the Apple Documentation in following link. Thanks!

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08282015a

Comment: @TuanAnh: No, you are the one who is missing knowledge. You are the one who should read the documentation again.

Comment: @dgatwood: You are contradicting yourself as you admit that the resolver does resolve IPv4 addresses to IPv6 addresses. IPv4 addresses do not "not work" -- they absolutely *work*, you just have to use the resolver to resolve them. The OS provides the API to resolve them, as documented in the Apple documentation. If you use a higher-level API (as in the question), you don't even need to manually resolve the IPv4 addresses -- it is transparently handled for you. So this answer is absolutely wrong for this question.

Comment: I don't know if I read it wrong originally or if they've updated it, but sure enough, NSURLSession et al automatically synthesize it for IP addresses, so there's basically no way any modern code should ever run into problems unless you're using POSIX calls.

Comment: @user102008 IPv4 literals work fine  ** if you must transfer IPv4 to IPv6** . The first, my comment's intent is want to know API_URL's type. Then, base recieve answer, I decide the resolution.

Comment: @TuanAnh: Whether API_URL is an IPv4 literal or not is not relevant here -- either way it will work in the code given in the question.